# Using a priority queue on a non-comparable object with a comparable object inside it

Tags: java, priority-queue, comparable, huffman-code

I'm building a huffman tree for a class currently. After reviewing my available options I decided to go the priority queue method. However, when I try to run the below code I get a ClassCastException on TreeNode (on the first pq.offer line).

```
public static TreeNode<CharFreq> buildTree(ArrayList<TreeNode<CharFreq>> trees) throws IOException {

   PriorityQueue<TreeNode<CharFreq>> pq = new PriorityQueue<TreeNode<CharFreq>>();

   for (int i = 0; i < trees.size(); i++) {
     if (trees.get(i).getItem().getFreq() > 0) {
       pq.offer(new TreeNode<CharFreq>(new CharFreq(trees.get(i).getItem().getChar(), trees.get(i).getItem().getFreq())));
     }
   }  

   while (pq.size() > 1) {    
       TreeNode<CharFreq> leftNode = pq.poll();
       TreeNode<CharFreq> rightNode = pq.poll();
       TreeNode<CharFreq> parentNode = new TreeNode<CharFreq>(new CharFreq('\u0000', ((leftNode.getItem().getFreq()) + (rightNode.getItem().getFreq()))), leftNode, rightNode);
   }  

   return pq.poll();

}
```

I know it's not a comparable class, however, CharFreq is, and my question is am I able to fix my code so it avoids this casting problem?

Comment: In case you have access to TreeNode code, You could add _compareTo()_ method to it and implement _Comparable_ interface. This could turn out to be easier for job you want to do. In this case your TreeNode contained elements should be always Comparables.

Comment: To provide better answer, it would be helpful to see implementation of TreeNode class. You could edit this question and add it here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a custom comparator: `Comparator<TreeNode<CharFreq>>` and use it when creating the PriorityQueue:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/PriorityQueue.html#PriorityQueue(int, java.util.Comparator)

> Creates a PriorityQueue with the specified initial capacity that orders its elements according to the specified comparator

Using the [anonymous class](http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/java-ent/jnut/ch03_12.htm) concept, you can have a code like this:

```
public static TreeNode<CharFreq> buildTree(ArrayList<TreeNode<CharFreq>> trees)
    throws IOException {
    Comparator<TreeNode<CharFreq>> comparator = new Comparator<TreeNode<CharFreq>>() {

        //basic implementation, you must use your own!
        public int compare(TreeNode<CharFreq> node1, TreeNode<CharFreq> node2) {
            return node1.data.compareTo(node2.data);
        }
    };
    PriorityQueue<TreeNode<CharFreq>> pq = new PriorityQueue<TreeNode<CharFreq>>(10, comparator);
    //the rest of your code...
}
```

Note that using this way means that you have to create a custom `Comparator<TreeNode<YourClass>>` everytime you need to create a `PriorityQueue<TreeNode<YourClass>>`.

Comment: In place of: "node1.compareTo(node2);" You should have "node1.getCharFreq().compareTo(node2.getCharFreq());" But that is assuming You have _getCharFreq()_ method in TreeNode. You might have something more generic there, like _getContent()_, but it is needed to be able to access the inner element in TreeNode, otherwise You have to revrite TreeNode to be comparable.

Comment: @Lauri right, answer edited. By the way, OP doesn't show how the data is stored in its `TreeNode` class, I'm assuming it could be a `data` property or similar.

Comment: Alright, built the comparator, however, I'm not sure how to implement it. I've got:


PriorityQueue<TreeNode<CharFreq>> pq = new PriorityQueue<TreeNode<CharFreq>>(trees.size(), comparator)


but that yells at me for referencing non-static comparator in a static context.

Comment: @Darkstarone did you create the `Comparator` inside the method, right? I've edited my answer to show you how to do it.

Comment: Ahh, thank you very much. Makes a lot more sense now. First foray into priority Queues tonight. Thanks for making it easier!

Answer (score 0):

The priority queue is using either a `Comparator` (provided in constructor) or it directly casts the object into `Comparable`.

To avoid the ClassCastException you should provide a `Comparator` of `TreeNode`. This way the queue will use the comparator instead of casting.

```
PriorityQueue<TreeNode<CharFreq>> pq = new PriorityQueue<TreeNode<CharFreq>>(initialCapacity, comparator);
```

Comment: The issue with creating a Comparator is that I'm unable to alter the TreeNode class due to assignment constraints!

Comment: @Darkstarone you don't need to modify your `TreeNode` class to make a `Comparator`. Look at my answer to see a basic implementation.